# scala - how to bind a variable name in a multiple pattern matching clause

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I want to pattern match using the same "`case`" to 2 different `case classes` but I am getting an error that the binded variable name is already in use:

for instance this:

```
statement match {
  case FirstCase(a,b) => {lots of logic using "a" and "b"}
  case SecondCase( obj : FirstCase, somethingElse) => {same logic as above}
  ...
  ...
}
```

I'd love to re-use the same logic :

```
statement match {
  case obj: FirstCase | SecondCase( obj : FirstCase, somethingElse) => 
{lots of logic using "obj.a" and "obj.b"}
  ...
  ...
}
```

But I am getting a compile error `"obj is already defined in scope"`

Is it possible to "re-use" the name of the binded object?

Comment: Why not just extract it into a new method?

Comment: I ended up doing it but it is tedius when you have lots of similar cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use helper method:

```
  def hlp(a: TypeOfA, b: TypeOfB) = ???

  statement match {
    case FirstCase(a, b) => hlp(a, b)
    case SecondCase(FirstCase(a, b), somethingElse) => hlp(a, b)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives to the other answer:

You can use intermediate variables:

```
val (a,b) = statement match {
   case FirstCase(a,b) => a -> b
   case SecondCase(FirstCase(a,b), somethingElse) => a -> b
}
// Use a and b
```

You can create an extractor object

```
object AB {
  def unapply(x: Any) = x match {
   case FirstCase(a,b) => Some(a -> b)
   case SecondCase(FirstCase(a,b), somethingElse) => Some(a -> b)
 }
}

statement match {
   case AB(a,b) => // use a and b here (you don't need the braces btw
}
```